# Make a view generic and usable with TYPE as well as Binding<TYPE>

Tags: generics, swiftui

I just had a situation where I wanted to use a view which, takes a String, with a Binding:

```
struct MyButton: View {
    
    var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Button{
            HStack {
                Text(text)
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't get it to work in an acceptable time period, so I just created a second view:

```
struct MyBoundedButton: View {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Button{
            HStack {
                Text(text)
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously works, but doesn't seem to be the most elegant solution. I tried to figure out how the SwiftUI framework does it, since there are plenty of examples of views which have very different initialisers (see the SwiftUI Button for instance). I still want to figure out how this might work, so since after work I'm trying to play around with generic view, but can't really get it to work. The following code doesn't work and is just to demonstrate the line of thinking I'm following:

```
struct MyButton<T>: View {
        
        var text: T
        
        var body: some View {
            Button{
                HStack {
                    Text(text)
                }   
            }
        }
    }

extension MyButton where text == Binding<String>{
    init(text: Binding<String>)
}

extension MyButton where text == String{
    init(text: String)
}
```

Does someone have an idea how this could be implemented or how Apple does this in their SwiftUI library?

Cheers,
Philip

Comment: What do you want to achieve? A single struct that could be text (no binding) and a text that is a binding? (just to clarify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done different ways... your approach with generics seems more elegant, but I believed that you are seeking a more understandable code, simpler:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyButton: View {
    
    private var text: Binding<String>?
    private var pureText: String?
    private var action: () -> Void
    
    init(text: Binding<String>, action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.action = action
        self.text = text
    }
    
    init(text: String, action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.action = action
        self.pureText = text
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            if let text = text {
                Text(text.wrappedValue)
            }
            if let text = pureText {
                Text(text)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var text = "Press me"
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            
            MyButton(text: $text) {
                print("Button pressed.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although the binding in this case doesn't make much sense... binding is when you are changing the value of the variable and want to pass UP to the ParentView, a binding inside a Text(text) that will never change doesn't make sense to me, but this is how you done with multiple initializers.

Comment: I tried to make work with Generics, but no luck as well. Generics work with kinds that are similar... and Binding and String are very different, there is no Protocol that could make the generic Type a Binding and also conform with String protocol. When we are talking about Generics, it's not REALLY generic, but two types with similar functionality. Like Primitive Types. I also tried with ENUM, but is the same as having two inits. So I think the best approach is the one that I already posted. With the DISCLAIMER, you don't need a Binding<String> unless you are trying push data UP.

Comment: In other hand, if you are trying to make a View that show Strings and Ints for instance, you could change every place where String appear and put T in there... and the declaration will be MyButton<T>, but if you are trying to show this into the Text() View, maybe is a good idea to make this T: StringInterpolationProtocol, to work with \() inside the " into the `Text("My Value \(value)")`. And keep the implementation with two inits.